# Ways to log MySQL Diff?

Tags: mysql, sql, comparison, diff

I'm working on a project right now that required me to use a CMS that makes multiple changes to a database, I'll need those changes later in order to create a post install configuration file to reuse those changes. I know that there are lots of Windows based programs that will show you MySQL Diffs, but what about Linux? I would like the ability to keep an appending log of my changes so I know what exactly is going on under the hood.

The ideal scenario would be that I can capture a post and current state, compare them, and aggregate the output. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: It seems like you are asking about database versioning. There have been many previous threads on that, such as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857977/database-versioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are the only changes made to your database then one way to do this is to enable the [binary log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html), and use that as your change log. You can convert it to a SQL script using the `mysqlbinlog` tool.